# Why CSS not working not working all of a sudden and what is \u200b?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validation-engine

I am working on an MVC application and all of a sudden the jQuery validation stopped showing the red rectangle and other styles related to errors on controls. I spent about 2 hours and for the life of me could not figure out what is wrong. Then I saw the red dot at the end of the tunnel, ok joking, but I really did notice a red dot in my CSS in Chrome debugger as shown below:

[image]

What the hell is that? I scrolled over it and the tooltip showed: **\u200b**

**Questions:**

1. So what is `\u200b`?
2. How do I get rid of it?
3. And could this be causing the issue?

Hopefully this will help some other poor programmer who, like me, does not have special superhero powers.

Comment: Backspace, copy and paste ;) (Remove the character in the debugger, copy all the code, and paste it back into your file.)

Comment: @ChrisHappy it is for knowledge sharing. I have already taken care of it.

Answer (score 2):

**1. What is `\u220b`?**

`\u200b` is [Zero Width Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) character. This from Wikipedia:

> The zero-width space (ZWSP) is a non-printing character used in computerized typesetting to indicate word boundaries to text processing systems when using scripts that do not use explicit spacing, or after characters (such as the slash) that are not followed by a visible space but after which there may nevertheless be a line break. Normally, it is not a visible separation, but it may expand in passages that are fully justified.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)

Great! It is not visible. I thought programmers have special powers and can see every thing but for the millionth time, I am realizing I am not one of those programmers.

**2. How do I get rid of it?**

I use VS 2015 for development and it shows nothing about this character as shown below:

[image]

Anyhow to get rid of it.

**First Attempt**

I went to the spot where the red dot is and pressed backspace and delete. But the red dot totally dodged it and I ended up deleting my code:

[image]

**Second Attempt**

I took out another weapon called *Regex* like shown below to find the red dot and replaced it with an empty space:

[image]

Bang! Gone!

**3. Could this be causing the issue?**

YES! Turns out it was that little *bug*ger that was causing the issue. Everything is back to normal once I remove it. I have no idea how I ended up with it in the first place.

I will call this day: *The Day I Saw the Red Dot*

The only question now, how will I explain to my client what I did for the past few hours??

Comment: Always a mystery to me how they ever get in there in the first place. Doesn't happen very often but when it does seems to come out of nowhere. Note that I never use visual studio so not isolated to that IDE either

Comment: add for deleting way. if your text is a[newline]b[ZWS][newline]c . why not just try to select a-c and just backspace?